# Torify and Torsocks not working

Tags: 16.04, tor, tor-browser

I want to Tor in terminal. This is what I used to do and it was working without any issue:

- running Tor Browser
- running `torify` or `torsocks` before the command in terminal

But it is for a while that this is not working. I don't remember if this is happening after some specific change in my system or not. I haven't had any major and noticeable change in it.

Perhaps the following lines can help for knowing the issue:

```
$ curl ifconfig.me
111.222.333.444       <<< My real IP

$ torify curl ifconfig.me 2> /dev/null 

$ torify curl ifconfig.me
[Jan 21 20:55:05] PERROR torsocks[16007]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:185)

$ torsocks curl ifconfig.me
[Jan 21 20:59:50] ERROR torsocks[16100]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:666)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ifconfig.me
```

While I'm facing this issue, I can easily use Tor Browser with no problem.

Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After spending lot of time and energy, I finally could manage to solve the problem myself.

It seems by default, Tor should be set in such a way to use the port 9050 for socks5. This setting can be found in `/etc/tor/torsocks.conf` file. Look at these lines in this file:

```
# Default Tor address and port. By default, Tor will listen on localhost for
# any SOCKS connection and relay the traffic on the Tor network.
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9050
```

Based on my TorBrowser setting, the browser uses port 9150 instead of 9050. So, I changed the relevant line and set 9150 as the port.

Now, `torsocks` and `torify` work as expected.
(Just it seems there is some technical issue with ifconfig.me website, since I cannot open it even in browser. But other websites are working well.)

Comment: Did you change torrc file or torsocks.conf? for Torsocks.conf shows 9150 as the TorPort but still the exact same error as you had.

Comment: Do you use TorBrowser or Tor service?

Comment: I have TorBrowser which is working fine, but I can not use torsocks. I have tor service running

Comment: Have you tried to change TorPort to 9050?

Comment: You can also specify the port with option, for e.g.:
`torsocks -P 9150 curl https://ipinfo.io/json`

Answer (score 2):

had this happen to me and also figured out what caused it: the tor port was left in a `close_wait` state after running a script with torify which means the port can't be opened for a short while so torify will not work until that port is released from `close_wait`